# Menú collapsible no funciona por Vue.js

Tags: bootstrap, vue.js, menú

Estoy utilizando la plantilla [Gentelella](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html) en un proyecto con el que también estoy utilizando [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) y me veo en la necesidad aplicar un objeto Vue que afecte al menú collapsible y a la top bar para controlar privilegios de usuario, el problema esta en que cuando el menú collapsible es encerrado en un contenedor que es afectado por Vue ya no funciona, las animaciones del menú simplemente dejan de funcionar y talvez ustedes me puedan ayudar a solucionar este problema, he intentado varias cosas pero la verdad nada me ha funcionado.

Hice un [ejemplo del problema](https://codepen.io/Villatoro/pen/JvZZVL?editors=1010) para que me entiendan mejor, en el JS, comenten la linea número 2 y las animaciones funcionaran, si la descomentan ya no funcionaran.

Comment: haciendo click en [`editar`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/164106/edit) podes incluir el ejemplo con CTRL+M , podes incluir librerías externas (JS y CSS). Las url de los JS y CSS los podes ver en los pen settings (del ejemplo).

Comment: Pon las librerias que estas usando, ya que lo mas probable es que sea incopatibilidad de script, (me sucedio algo parecido)

Comment: En el ejemplo que doy pongo las librerías que utilizo, ya que hice una prueba solamente con esas librerias tratando de "limpiar" un poco en cuanto a utilización de scripts y de la misma forma no funcionaba el menú.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder tener el mismo efecto del `template` `html` es necesario almacenar en un data el nombre de la `class` `'nav-md'` y `'nav-sm'` asociando-le un evento `click` que te realizara el cambio recordando que tu `html` debe estar encapsulado en tu componente `vue`.

Debes crear un `array` con la información del menú y usar `v-for` para crearlo, en el siguiente fragmento de código podrás ver como funciona:

```js
var menus = [{
    label: 'Home',
    icon: 'fa fa-home',
    class: 'active',
    children: [{
        label: 'Dashboard',
        href: '#'
      },
      {
        label: 'Dashboard2',
        href: '#'
      },
      {
        label: 'Dashboard3',
        href: '#'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'Home2',
    icon: 'fa fa-home',
    children: [{
        label: 'Dashboard4',
        href: '#'
      },
      {
        label: 'Dashboard5',
        href: '#'
      },
      {
        label: 'Dashboard6',
        href: '#'
      }
    ]
  }
]

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#root_app_vue",
  data: {
    class_menu: 'nav-md',
    active: undefined
  },

  mounted: function() {

  },
  methods: {
    menu: function() {
      if (this.class_menu == 'nav-md') {
        this.class_menu = 'nav-sm'
      } else {
        this.class_menu = 'nav-md'
      }

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://colorlib.com/polygon/build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Gentelella Alela! | </title>
</head>

<body class="">
  <div id="root_app_vue">
    <div v-bind:class="[class_menu]">
      <div class="container body">
        <div class="main_container">
          <div id="as">
            <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
              <div class="left_col scroll-view">
                <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
                  <a href="#" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> <span>Gentelella Alela!</span></a>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>

                <!-- menu profile quick info -->
                <div class="profile clearfix">
                  <div class="profile_pic">
                    <img src="https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/images/img.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
                  </div>
                  <div class="profile_info">
                    <span>Welcome,</span>
                    <h2>John Doe</h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- /menu profile quick info -->

                <br />

                <!-- sidebar menu -->
                <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
                  <div class="menu_section">
                    <h3>General</h3>
                    <ul class="nav side-menu">
                      <li v-for="menu in menus" :class="[{active:menu.label == active},menu.class]" @click="active:menu.label == active? active='' : active = menu.label"><a><i :class="[ menu.icon ]"></i> {{ menu.label }} <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav child_menu" v-bind:style="[menu.label == active || menu.class ? { display:'block' } : { display: 'none' } ]">
                          <li v-for="submenu in menu.children"><a :href=" submenu.href ">{{ submenu.label }} </a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>

                    </ul>
                  </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /sidebar menu -->

                <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
                <div class="sidebar-footer hidden-small">
                  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Settings">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="FullScreen">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Lock">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Logout" href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- top navigation -->
            <div class="top_nav">
              <div class="nav_menu">
                <nav>
                  <div class="nav toggle">
                    <a id="menu_toggle" @click="menu()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                  </div>

                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="">
                      <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img src="https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/images/img.jpg" alt="">John Doe
                        <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                      </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu pull-right">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;"> Profile</a></li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="javascript:;">
                            <span class="badge bg-red pull-right">50%</span>
                            <span>Settings</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                      <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle info-number" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        <span class="badge bg-green">6</span>
                      </a>
                      <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list" role="menu">
                        <li>
                          <a>
                            <span class="image"><img src="https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                            <span>
                            <span>John Smith</span>
                            <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="message">
                            Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
                          </span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a>
                            <span class="image"><img src="https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                            <span>
                            <span>John Smith</span>
                            <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="message">
                            Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
                          </span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a>
                            <span class="image"><img src="https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                            <span>
                            <span>John Smith</span>
                            <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="message">
                            Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
                          </span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a>
                            <span class="image"><img src="https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                            <span>
                            <span>John Smith</span>
                            <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="message">
                            Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
                          </span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <div class="text-center">
                            <a>
                              <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                              <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /top navigation -->
          </div>

          <!-- page content -->
          <div class="right_col" role="main">
            <div class="">
              <div class="page-title">
                <div class="title_left">
                  <h3>Plain Page</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="title_right">
                  <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right top_search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="clearfix"></div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                  <div class="x_panel">
                    <div class="x_title">
                      <h2>Plain Page</h2>
                      <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                        <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="x_content">
                      Add content to the page ...
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /page content -->

          <!-- footer content -->
          <footer>
            <div class="pull-right">
              Gentelella - Bootstrap Admin Template by <a href="https://colorlib.com">Colorlib</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </footer>
          <!-- /footer content -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Si la respuesta a solucionado tu problema, no olvides dar tu voto positivo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! tu respuesta me dio un gran aporte para por fin hacer lo que queria, que eran permisos en el menu utilizando vue.js, Gracias :)

Comment: De nada @Villatoro, me alegra poder ayudarte.

Comment: Viendo el ejemplo ya descargado, pierde la propiedad que la opción que seleccionas del menú aparece activa automáticamente... habría forma de recrear este funcionamiento de la plantilla? o volverlo a inicializar de alguna forma?

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la respuesta, no se si es lo que me preguntabas.

Answer (score 1):

El manejador del evento click de tu menú no funciona debido a que Vue lo ha desasociado al evento click. Por favor lee esta incidencia en GitHub para obtener más información: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3587

Debes indicar a Vue qué parte del DOM gestionará JQuery tal y como se indica en https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/. De no hacer esto, Vue eliminará cualquier manejador de eventos que asocies sin informarle en sus ciclos de actualización.

Comment: ¿Puedo saber el motivo de los votos negativos? Dar una implementación no siempre es la forma de responder la pregunta. He indicado qué debe hacer para resolver el problema. En la documentación se dan ejemplos de código. El método funciona, como puede verse en este fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crabbly/9o69f2yr/